# SQL Query Error in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

On Exeuting Following Query:

```
SELECT ID
  FROM INSTITUTE
 WHERE MEMBER_ID IN (
    SELECT ID 
      FROM MEMBER 
     WHERE ID IN (765,769,753,774,778,779,781,790,799,809,
                  820,823,855,835,839,842,845,849,850,851)
    ORDER BY NAME ASC
)
```

I am getting following error:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 81
```

How can I troubleshoot this bug???

Comment: Why are you nesting so many subselects? The issue is the ORDER BY in the second subselect.

Answer (score 3):

Your ORDER BY is inside your subselect and therefore useless to the final order of the results but is causing your error.

Move it outside the subselect.

```
SELECT id
  FROM institute
 WHERE member_id IN
          (  SELECT id
               FROM MEMBER
              WHERE id IN ( 765, 769, 753, 774, 778, 779, 781, 790,
                            799, 809, 820, 823, 855, 835, 839, 842,
                            845, 849, 850, 851 )
          )
 ORDER BY name ASC
```

N.B.: I can only assume that `name` is a column in the `institute` table as otherwise the `ORDER BY` would be totally redundant. Therefore it should be ordering the main `SELECT`.

or remove it entirely...

```
SELECT id
  FROM institute
 WHERE member_id IN
          (  SELECT id
               FROM MEMBER
              WHERE id IN ( 765, 769, 753, 774, 778, 779, 781, 790,
                            799, 809, 820, 823, 855, 835, 839, 842,
                            845, 849, 850, 851 )
          )
```

Wouldn't this query be more efficient though?

```
SELECT i.id
  FROM institute i
 INNER JOIN member m
    ON (i.member_id = m.id)
 WHERE m.id IN ( 765, 769, 753, 774, 778, 779, 781, 790,
                 799, 809, 820, 823, 855, 835, 839, 842,
                 845, 849, 850, 851 )
```

Comment: You are now ordering results by institute.name (if it exists), and I'm quite convinced that the OP wants the results order by member.name. Why not do a join on `institute.member_id = member.id` and remove the sub-select entirely?

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann it is possible - however, the OP never stated their intended use / output, so it would be a guess. But i agree that would be logical.

Comment: In trying to second guess the OP's table structure, not all answers are going to be perfect, it is just an approximation of what he is trying to achieve whilst removing the issue that has caused them to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ORDER BY` in the sub-select is useless. Consider joining the two tables instead, like this:

```
SELECT ID
FROM INSTITUTE i, MEMBER m
WHERE
i.MEMBER_ID = m.ID
AND i.MEMBER_ID IN
    (
        765,769,753,774,778,779,781,790,799,809,820,823,855,835,839,842,845,849,850,851
    )
ORDER BY m.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

order by should bu put out of the IN clause

```
SELECT ID
FROM INSTITUTE
WHERE MEMBER_ID IN (
SELECT ID FROM MEMBER WHERE ID IN (
765,769,753,774,778,779,781,790,799,809,820,823,855,835,839,842,845,849,850,851 )
)
ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

Comment: Everybody here seems to think that Institute has a `name` column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT ID 
FROM INSTITUTE 
WHERE MEMBER_ID IN (
SELECT ID FROM MEMBER WHERE ID IN (765,769,753,774,778,779,781,790,799,809,820,823,855,835,839,842,845,849,850,851))
ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

I suspect you need the `ORDER BY` statement outside of the `IN` clause

Comment: Everybody here seems to think that Institute has a `name` column?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID FROM INSTITUTE 
WHERE MEMBER_ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM MEMBER WHERE ID IN
( 765,769,753,774,778,779,781,790,799,809,820,823,855,835,839,842,845,849,850,851 )) ORDER BY NAME ASC;
```

Try this - your order by is in the wrong place.

Comment: Everybody here seems to think that Institute has a `name` column?

Comment: I thought this when writing the answer - but thought the best way to illustrate where an ORDER BY clause should be would be to illustrate by moving "NAME" outside to the main query. However i accept that there was no information supporting this decision.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your `ORDER BY` clause occurs inside the outer `MEMBER_ID IN(...)` clause.

This query looks suspiciously as though it should be accomplished with a `JOIN` instead of two `IN()` clauses:

```
SELECT INSTITUTE.id
FROM 
  INSTITUTE JOIN MEMBER ON INSTITUTE.MEMBER_ID = MEMBER.ID
WHERE MEMBER.ID IN IN (765,769,753,774,778,779,781,790,799,809,820,823,855,835,839,842,845,849,850,851)
ORDER BY MEMBER.NAME ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The `order by` in the subquery is completely useless, it won't order the output at all. Remove it and it will work.

Btw, moving it outside won't give the expected result, except `institute.name` has the same values as `member.name` ;-)